# How to I create an extension in c# to return a new date time entry that can be converted in linq to entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, extension-methods

So I have this property in a LinQ to entity query and I need to add days to it

```
isWithinNinetyDays = (a.ParcelData == null ? false :
    (a.ParcelData.Parcel_LetterTracking == null ? false : 
        (a.ParcelData.Parcel_LetterTracking.LMailDate == null ? false : 
            (System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(a.DateTimeEntry, 90) >= a.ParcelData.Parcel_LetterTracking.LMailDate.Value)))),
```

The issue is I don't want to use "System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(a.DateTimeEntry, 90)" because I'm going to have to do this a lot and it's just so ugly to write that everytime... is it possible to make an extension where I can just call

```
a.DateTimeEntry.MyExtension(90)
that will add 90 days and be able to convert it to a entity convertable to sql object?
```

Comment: The condition can logically be reduced considerably, but apart from that: if you need this computation so often then add a computed column to the table returning `DateTimeEntry` + 90 days. This will greatly simplify the EF predicate.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `using` statement.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
DBFunctions.AddDays(a.DateTimeEntry, 90) ...
```

Comment: this has compile error "using DB = System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions;" dbfunctions is a type which is not valid in the given context. Do you know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Neovssmith: [DBFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) is a `static` class.  Try my answer edit.

Comment: Will this work in an extension method such as public static DateTime? myExtension(this DateTime date) => DbFunctions.AddDays(date, 90);

Comment: It should.  Create a static class with the extension method, and call AddDays as above.